# Is there a VBA code to select multiple (and varied totals of) columns from multiple worksheets to copy and paste into a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy multiple columns from multiple worksheets into a new worksheet in Excel using a VBA Macro.

I have already created the worksheet, and I want to paste specific columns one after another in that worksheet.

I would like to copy from each worksheet all columns including and beyond a certain column, in all worksheets including and from Column F.

I have written a piece of code that selects the appropriate data and loops correctly.

However, i get a "run-time error 1004", **when the loop hits a worksheet where I am copying only one column.**

I know this is because of the choice of my code. However, I don't know how to solve the problem.

The problem is that my code selects a range to the end of the worksheet when there is only one column being selected. This creates a copied area too big to paste in the new worksheet.

```
Dim i As Integer
        
        i = 1
        
        Do While i <= Worksheets.Count - 1
        Worksheets(i).Select
        
        'Select, Copy and Paste Data
        
        RangeFromF1
        
        Selection.Copy
        
        Worksheets("Combined").Select
        
        Range("X1").Select
        
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        
        i = i + 1
        
        Loop

End Sub

Public Sub RangeFromF1()

       Range("F1", Range("F1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going from column F to the right, try going from the last column to the left.

```
Public Sub RangeFromF1()

       Range("F1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown)).Select

End Sub
```

You might also want to get rid of all the Select stuff.

```
Sub CopyStuff()
Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    Do While i <= Worksheets.Count - 1

        With Worksheets(i)

            .Range("F1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown)).Copy

            Worksheets("Combined").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Paste

            i = i + 1
            
        End With

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, wow, so quick! Thanks. Before giving up and going to bed I had come to the conclusion that going backwards was the answer but i couldn't figure it out!

Thanks for the smarter code, too. I am totally new to this and was playing with a code from an online course, where they simplify everything.

Comment: Range("F1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown)).Select - I'm not sure of the syntax here. It's telling it to create a range From F1, then go to last Cell in the last column and (in the same row i.e. 1) "Cells(1, Columns.Count)". Then left, then down?

Answer (score 0):

Before coming back to check for your answer noris, I figured out a way, to do as you suggested, with the following code:

```
Public Sub ReferenceSelection()

Dim startcell As Range
 
 Set startcell = Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)
 
Range(startcell, ("F1")).Select

End Sub
```